# Heroku Rails App Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=www.blocked.ca request_id=64d4a40e-88e7-4819-9200-bd3c9fafc6ac fwd="208.115.111.72/208-115-111-72-reverse.wowrack.com" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=333

app web.1 - - [INFO] [Started GET "/uploads/1/2/4/5/12454275/1255727_orig.jpg" for 188.165.15.32/boson020.ahrefs.com at 2015-01-11 12:43:38 +0000] (pid:2)

app web.1 - - [FATAL] [ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/1/2/4/5/12454275/1255727_orig.jpg"):

app web.1 - - vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'

app web.1 - - vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'

I'm getting this error on one of my heroku App while idle what is causing it ?

Comment: format the code, and provide more info about the issue.

Comment: the app works fine I just get error sometime during idle it doesn't crash